# asp.net core: Preserve ForeignKey Relation in JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When i send an object from my database (EntityFramework) using JsonResult without foreign key i get the result i need. If this object contains a ForeignKey relation the relation is not in the resulting json:

What i get:

```
{
    "agentId":"9990447f-6703-11e7-9c8b-94de80ab7fee",
    ...
    "configurationId": 22,
    "configuration": null
}
```

What i need:

```
{
    "agentId":"9990447f-6703-11e7-9c8b-94de80ab7fee",
    ...
    "configurationId": 22,
    "configuration": {
        "id": 0,
        ...
    }
}
```

> What can i do to preserve this foreign key relation in my json?

I already tried to set the following:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All);
```

EF Context:

```
public class Agent
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AgentId { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? ConfigurationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ConfigurationId")]
    public Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var agentList = _databaseContext.Agents;
    return new JsonResult(agentList);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the [related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var agentList = _databaseContext.Agents
                                    .Include(agent=> agent.Configuration)
                                    .ToList();;
    return new JsonResult(agentList);
}
```

Comment: This "kinda" works, i get the configuration object in my json. Problem is, i only get the first agent object with this and not a list of all agents.

Comment: To clarify, i can see that linq returns multiple agents but the resulting json only contains one.

Comment: I found the problem. `PreserveReferencesHandling.All` is still needed or include will not work. I just changed it to `PreserveReferencesHandling.Object`